# Rendering browser through OpenGL

Tags: opengl, embedded

I have a browser running on am embedded platform, and I am wondering if there is any advantage to rendering straight to OpenGL.  One that comes to mind is the cross-platform access to hardware acceleration.  Is anyone aware of any other advantages that may make the work worth it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The would depend nearly entirely on the embedded platform in question.  Many embedded platforms have little or no hardware acceleration, in which case, it will not help.

However, if it does, and if the native browsers on your device are not already accelerated, there may be some benefit to this.  You'll have to decide whether the extra work involved is worth any benefits gained, though.